# How to limit the number of keypoints found by Kaze?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I'm using cv2.KAZE_Create() to find the keypoints in an image. Is there a way I can limit the number of matches to speed up the computation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenCV C++ documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d61/classcv_1_1KAZE.html#gsc.tab=0) :

```
static Ptr<KAZE> cv::KAZE::create   (   bool    extended = false,
        bool    upright = false,
        float   threshold = 0.001f,
        int     nOctaves = 4,
        int     nOctaveLayers = 4,
        int     diffusivity = KAZE::DIFF_PM_G2 
    )
```

So, I think you can `tweak the parameters (increase threshold, nOctaves...)` so you limit your number of detected points.

PS: I may be using C++ not Python, but according to [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_bindings/py_bindings_basics/py_bindings_basics.html#bindings-basics), it should be the same.

Comment: Will I have to build Opencv again?

Comment: which version are you using ? 3.1.0 ?

Comment: Yes, I;m using 3.1.0.

Comment: I think you shouldn't rebuild, just try the following `cv2.KAZE_Create(false, false, 0.001f, 4, 4)`, if it works correctly, so just tweak the arguments for a best match.